# Creating 2 y axes in ggplot with count and cumulative count

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

Here's some dummy data

```
dummy <- data.frame(numbers = 1:5,
symptomdate  = as.Date(c("2012-08-30", "2012-08-30", "2012-08-31", "2012-09-01", "2012-09-01")),
reporteddate = as.Date(c("2012-09-02", "2012-09-03", "2012-09-05", "2012-09-07", "2012-09-08")),
dateofdeath   = as.Date(c("2012-09-10", NA, NA, NA, "2012-09-31")),
gender = c("Female", "Male", "Male","Female", "Male"),
position = c("Resident", "Staff", "Resident", "Staff", "Staff"), 
outbreakdate = as.Date(c("2012-08-31","2012-08-31","2012-08-31","2012-08-31","2012-08-31")))
```

each observation is a 'case'. I would like to create a histogram which shows the case count on the y axis, and also have a secondary y-axis which shows the cumulative count of cases, but I can't figure out how to make it using 'sec.axis'. Do I need to add a cumulative count to my dataframe first?

What I have so far:

```
ggplot(dummy, aes(x= symptomdate, group = position, fill = position)) +  stat_bin(colour = "black", binwidth = 0.5, alpha = 1, position = "identity") + theme_bw() + 
  xlab("Symptom date") + ylab("Number of cases") + scale_x_date(breaks= date_breaks("1 day"), labels = date_format("%b-%d")) + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) + theme(legend.position="top")  +  scale_fill_manual(values = my_colours)
```

I know this must be simple but I've looked at countless posts and can't figure it out. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. With your dummy data you can create the variables for cases and cumulative counts. After computing the scaling factor, you can reshape to long and sketch the plot with the desired structure. Here the code, where `tidyverse` functions have been used over `dummy` dataframe:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
newdf <- dummy %>% group_by(symptomdate) %>%
  summarise(Count=n()) %>% ungroup() %>%
  mutate(Cum=cumsum(Count))
#Scaling factor
sf <- max(newdf$Count)
newdf$Cum <- newdf$Cum/sf
#plot
newdf %>%
  pivot_longer(-symptomdate) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=symptomdate)) +
  geom_bar( aes(y = value, fill = name, group = name),
            stat="identity", position=position_dodge(),
            color="black", alpha=.6)  +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue", "red")) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Cases",sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*sf, name="Cum Cases"))+
  labs(fill='Variable')+
  theme_bw()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! How do I keep some of the other variables (gender, age etc) when creating the new dataset?

Comment: @mobo1 In that case you should play around `mutate()` or using smt like `dummy %>% left_join(newdf)` Just be careful, in the plot you can put all those variables. Just take care of that. I hope this answer was useful for you!

Comment: That worked! This was INCREDIBLY helpful, thank you!!!